# Can you call a module from a userform whose variable is declared from a combo box?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform sub that will allow the user to choose from the open workbook to use as the reference workbook using a combo box.  My current script is returning an error that `workbooks(wb)` is not defined - I assume this is because the variable is defined in two different modules and the combo box is not in the module being called. Ideally would like to use the userform below

```
Private Sub Go_Click()

 If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a workbook name and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

  Dim wb As Variant

  wb = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)

  Call GenerateReportUserForm

End Sub
```

To call this sub:

```
Sub newMacro()

Dim copyNames As Range, pasteNames As Range, copyAmounts As Range, pasteAmounts As Range, copyDates As Range, pasteDates As Range, _
copyPayment As Range, pastePayment As Range

'   For cheques only

Set copyNames = Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(2).Columns("F")
Set copyAmounts = Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(2).Columns("AR")
Set copyDates = Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(2).Columns("AI")
Set copyPayment = Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(2).Columns("AJ")

Set pasteNames = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set pasteAmounts = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set pasteDates = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D")
Set pastePayment = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("E")

copyNames.Copy Destination:=pasteNames
copyAmounts.Copy Destination:=pasteAmounts
copyDates.Copy Destination:=pasteDates
copyPayment.Copy Destination:=pastePayment

End sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'wb' needs to be declared as public at procedure level, or passed into `newmacro` like so `newmacro(wb as variant)`

Comment: Remember to set objects when declaring - set wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.ListIndex)

Comment: Adding to spoken above - add an `Option Explicit` statement at the top of your modules and it will show many of your errors at compile time and will help you avoid such exceptions.

Comment: Thanks!  Would ````Dim newMacro(wb As Variant)```` be in the userform or module? Seems that it is asking for a separator when I attempt to declare it.

Comment: Well you 'Call' not 'Dim' newMacro. But I would use newMacro(wb as workbook) and use what I said above. Then in newMacro use set copyNames = wb.sheets(2).columns("F") etc.

Comment: Missing something? It does not recognize it and asking for a separator (GenerateReportUserForm is the actual name of the module, forgot to change it)   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvL03.png

Comment: @patriciajlim see answer below

Comment: You can't call a *module*, you call a *procedure*.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot. SO is wonderful, especially as a beginner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wb` clearly wants to be a `String` representing the name of a workbook. Declare it as such.

```
Dim wbName As String
wbName = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
```

Side note, **name** your controls. `AvailableFilesBox` tells so much more than `ComboBox1`.

Now, what you want is to pass this variable as an argument; **do not use a global variable** unless you absolutely MUST.

> ```
> Call GenerateReportUserForm
> ```

Not sure what this is supposed to be doing, but it's not calling `newMacro`. If you want to make it call `newMacro`, then change it to this:

```
NewMacro wbName
```

Or if you really really want to keep that redundant and distracting `Call` keyword:

```
Call NewMacro(wbName)
```

Note: give that macro a meaningful name that describes what the macro does. "new macro" might be clear *now*, but not so much once there are 4-5 newer macros in that project - and `newMacro2` is NOT an option!

Now, in order to pass `wbName` as an argument, the procedure needs to declare that it takes a parameter - like this:

```
Public Sub NewMacro(ByVal wbName As String)
```

Inside that procedure scope, you don't need to constantly dereference the `Workbook` object. Do it *once*, store the object reference into a local variable, then use that variable:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)
```

Turns out, that macro doesn't really care for the workbook's name; what it really actually wants is a `Workbook` object. So, let's make it the caller's responsibility to provide a `Workbook`.

First we change the signature to take a `Workbook` parameter:

```
Public Sub NewMacro(ByVal wb As Workbook)
```

Then we change the form code to supply it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex))

NewMacro wb ' or: Call NewMacro(wb)
```

Remember to always put `Option Explicit` at the top of every module; [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) can help you find & fix this, and other issues in your code.